# TreeView with multiple leaf data types in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am trying to create a TreeView with the following hierarchy:

```
Device1
--File1
--File2
--Hook1
--Hook2
Device2
--File1
--File1
Device3
--Hook1
```

So basically The Root level node is a device with children being File and Hook. I have created the following tree with the hierarchical data template

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}">
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type datamodel:Device}" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
               <TextBlock Margin="5,5,0,0" Text="{Binding DeviceName}"/>
                  <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type datamodel:File}">
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                 </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
       </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

```
     Class Devices
     {

          public string DeviceName
          {
             get;set;
          }

          public string List<File> Files
          {
              get;set;
          }

         public string List<Hook> Hooks
          {
              get;set;
          }
     }

  public class File
{
     public string FileName
     {
        get;set;
     }


     public string FileType
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public string Location
    {
        get; set;
    }

}


public class Hook
{
    public string HookName
    {
       get;set;
    }

    public string Type
   {
      get;set;
   }
}
```

I am able to add only one Datatemplate in the ItemTemplate of the HierarchicalDataTemplate. How do I specify two data types under a single HierarchicalDataTemplate??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with the CompositeCollection but realized that the bound objects were converted to base types. So I used it in combination of DataTemplateSelector.
The following solution worked for me.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}">
     <TreeView.Resources>
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type datamodel:Devices}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource LeafDataTemplateSelector}">
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                 <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CompositeCollectionConverter}">
                      <Binding Path="Files" />
                      <Binding Path="Hooks"/>
                 </MultiBinding>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <StackPanel Height="25" Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="Device.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,5,0,0" Text="{Binding Device}"/>
                </StackPanel>
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

         <DataTemplate x:Key="FileKey" DataType="{x:Type datamodel:File}">
                <StackPanel Height="25" Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="Installation File">
                     <Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="File.png" />
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:Key="HookKey"  DataType="{x:Type datamodel:Hook}">
               <StackPanel Height="25" Orientation="Horizontal"  ToolTip="Installation Hook">
                   <Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="Hook.png" />
                   <TextBlock Margin="5,5,0,0" Text="{Binding HookName}"/>
               </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
```

The have used the template selector to select the appropriate template based on the key.

```
 public class LeafDataTemplateSelector :  DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate
        SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null)
        {

            if (item is InstallationManifesFile)
                return
                        element.FindResource("FileKey")
                        as DataTemplate;
            else if (item is InstallationManifestHook)
                return element.FindResource("HookKey")
                        as DataTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class CompositeCollectionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values
        , Type targetType
        , object parameter
        , System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var res = new CompositeCollection();
        foreach (var item in values)
            if (item is IEnumerable && item != null)
                res.Add(new CollectionContainer()
                {
                    Collection = item as IEnumerable
                });
        return res;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value
        , Type[] targetTypes
        , object parameter
        , System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the converter here which will return the `CompositeCollection` which will contain both files and hooks. You will use this converter with `ItemsSource` of `HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type datamodel:Device}"`

Then you just need to define two datatemplates for File and Hook data type.

Thanks